# Execute shell command and then some text into document

Tags: commands, shell-command

I have a python script `ss.py` that gets a screenshot from a connected device and puts into particular dir. From terminal I run it with the target path as an arg:

```
$ python ss.py {document-name}/{image-name}
```

Then I have to insert some text into my document to reference it.

```
.. image:: /img/{document-name}/{image-name}.*
  :alt: {Some alt text here}
```

I want to write a command that will accept the image name as an argument, take the doc name from the current buffer (minus file extension) and then put the `image` directive into the current buffer, leaving me and my cursor at the alt text, so I can keep writing there. And I want to bind it to some key (I don't what is commonly unused/available.)

(I am very new to emacs. So I don't even know where to start with this.)

NB: In case it matters, I need to run the Python command using python3, which normally means I use a virtualenv in a bash shell. Also, in case it matters I am using emacs 25 on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself...

```
(defun odk-ss (img-name)
  "Takes a screenshot of an attached Android device, saves it to /img/ and then inserts a referen\
ce to it in an rst document"
  (interactive "sImage name: ")
  (insert-before-markers (format ".. image:: /img/%s/%s.* \n  :alt:" (file-name-base) img-name)
                         )
  (shell-command (format "python ss.py %s/%s" (file-name-base) img-name)) ; shell command goes he\
re                                                                                                

  )

(global-set-key (kbd "M-.") 'odk-ss)
```

Comment: In that case you should accept your own answer so that other people will be sure that your question was answered to satisfaction

Comment: Yes. But StackExchange won't let me accept my own answer for several days.

Comment: Several days have elapsed :)

Comment: You probably want to use `shell-quote-argument` when generating your shell command, and I wouldn't recommend clobbering `M-.` which has a standard purpose; you can safely use any `C-c <letter>` sequence for your own purposes (where `<letter>` is any lower- or upper-case letter), as those are reserved for end-users.